# Is it valid to create object of class in which main method is present?

Tags: java

```java
public class Main {

    void something() {
        System.out.println("Works?");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.something();
    }
}
```

In the program above, I simply created an object of class `Main` inside method `main()`. Later I used that object to call `something()` method. The code works fine but, is this way of creating an object inside method `main()` valid?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. Since you want to call a non-static method, you need an instance. Simply creating it using `new` is not a problem at all, especially for smaller programs (the opposite would be factory methods or dependency injection etc).

Comment: You just compiled and run your code without problems which shows it is *allowed* in Java. But that is probably not what you want to ask about. So could you [edit] your question and clarify what do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: Yes, perfectly fine. Necessary.

Comment: I voted as opinion based. It can be done, but not necessary unless trying to use non-static class state. `static void something()` would also work here, then you don't need `new Main()` at all, and just call `something()`

Comment: Q: Is it valid to create object of class in which main method is present?  A: Yes, definitely.  In fact, having a "`public static void main(String[] args)`" used to be *ENCOURAGED* for *EVERY* class, to facilitate "unit testing" (a practice which has since fallen out of favor).  STRONG SUGGESTION: Please don't name your class "Main".  Please give it a name that tells something about what the class is *intended for*.

Answer (score 4):

Every Java app needs a `main` method. The `main` method is the [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) for launching a Java app.

That `public static void main` method must be placed in *some* class. That class may serve other purposes, or that class may serve that one single purpose of providing a entry point for launching the app’s lifecycle.

> is this way of creating object inside main() method is valid?

Yes, valid.

The choice is yours whether you want to instantiate objects of the class holding the `public static void main` method.

As [commented by paulsm4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932312/is-it-valid-to-create-object-of-class-in-which-main-method-is-present/75932488#comment133930270_75932312), in the olden days before the advent of formal [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) accompanied by sophisticated [tooling for testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit), programmers sometimes wrote a `public static void main` into most every class. Each of those `main` methods would test functionality coming primarily from that class. Only one of these many `main` methods would act as the entry point for formally launching the app for the end-user. All the other `main` methods were just a way to quickly run some tests of their containing class. These testing `main` methods would instantiate objects of their containing class in order to test the instance methods.

Keep in mind that any use of `static`, including for `main`, is *not* [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). But we have a [chicken-or-egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) problem. Object-oriented programming (OOP) assumes an ideal world of objects floating around in memory sending messages to each other. But that ideal world does not exist until *after* we launch our app. So a `static` main method is the trick, the hack if you will, to solving our chicken-or-egg dilemma, to get our ideal OOP world up and running. In other words, when I see `public static void main`, I personally think of that code as being outside my “real” app, and mentally set it aside.

Comment: "Must be placed in _some_ **public** class"?

Comment: @OneCricketeer The nitty-gritty details of scope and access is not really the point here.